# Is there a timer in BlackBerry 10 that runs your functions after a specified time interval?

Tags: timer, blackberry-10

I searched the internet but there is very little documentation available on BlackBerry 10 development. Is there something in BlackBerry 10 that allows you to run a function forever after specified intervals of time? Like there is NSTimer in iPhone/Objective-C that can run a function after every x minutes or so.

Comment: for someone to help you, you need to have done something yourself....

Comment: @MitchWheat what do i do really when I dont even know the direction in which I should work? I told you how I did this in older versions of blackberry.But the newer version doesnt support these events.So what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by @Sorry_Boss, you can use [QTimer](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/qtimer.html) on C++ code. If you want to do that in QML, you can also [register it for use in QML](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/dev/integrating_cpp_qml/) in the constructor of your app class, like this:

```
qmlRegisterType<QTimer>("my.library", 1, 0, "QTimer");
```

Then, you can import it in your QML file:

```
import my.library 1.0
```

... and use it as an attached object to another component:

```
attachedObjects: [
    QTimer {
        id: timer
        interval: 1000 // 1 second
        onTimeOut {
            // do something
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [QTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html).

```
QTimer timer = new QTimer(this);
timer->start(intervalTime);
```

Connect timeout signal of timer with your function.

```
QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this,
            SLOT(yourFunction()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this can be done with QTimer

In cpp

```
QTimer *timer= new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
timer->start(1000);

void AppName::update(){
//Do operation on timeout
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a more general answer, because you will likely run into the same problem again, you have to treat BB10 as a completely different operating system and development environment because it is. Unlike the old environment though, the documentation is actually quite good. For example finding information on timers is as simple as going to the Cascades [documentation site](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference), selecting API Reference and typing 'timer' into the filter text box.

You will also find a wealth of help in the form of sample applications and general documentation and guidelines.

[image]